# Count de arrays dentro de um objeto!

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tenho um objeto com arrays dentro, dentro desse array.. existem outro objetos! como consigo saber o length total de todos os arrays dentro do primeiro objeto! ex:

```js
    let items = { 
        0: [
            { foo: 'foo' },
            { bar: 'bar' },
        ], // length = 2 
        1: [
            { foo: 'foo' },
        ], // length = 1 
    }
    
    let total = 0;
    total += items[0].length;
    total += items[1].length;
    
    console.log(total);
```

Existe alguma forma menos verbosa para executar esse trecho ? exemplo se eu tiver 50~100 items fica inviável manter esse código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisa apenas de usar um loop que percorra todas as propriedades que existem no objeto, e somar os tamanhos dos arrays associados.

Assim:

```js
let items = { 
    0: [
        { foo: 'foo' },
        { bar: 'bar' },
    ], // length = 2 
    1: [
        { foo: 'foo' },
    ], // length = 1 
}

let total = 0;
for (let prop of Object.keys(items)){ //percorrer todas as propriedades
  total += items[prop].length; //somar o tamanho do array na propriedade corrente
}
    
console.log(total);
```

Fiz uso da função [`keys` de `Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) que devolve um array com todas as propriedades do objeto.